# How do you set the startup page size in dotnet MAUI for macOS(net6.0-maccatalyst)

Tags: c#, macos, maui, mac-catalyst, .net-maui

There is already a solution for windows, I need something similar, but for MacOS;
Solution for Windows: [MAUI .NET Set Window Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399551/maui-net-set-window-size)

Answer (score 2):

I independently found the answer to the question, below I attached the code:

```
private void SetMainWindowStartSize(int width, int height)
{
    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
        nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
        {
            var size = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(width, height);
            handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MinimumSize = size;
            handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MaximumSize = size;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MinimumSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(100, 100);
                    handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MaximumSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(5000, 5000);
                });
            });

        });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where you found this.;
It works for me in MacOs, kudos.
For me the complete solution in context.
I added this function to MainPage.xaml.cs

Note: This is a MACOS specific feature.
It needs platform specific wrapping.

Then I called the initial size I wanted in the mainpage function.

```
public MainPage()
{

    InitializeComponent();
                               
    SetMainWindowStartSize(300, 150);
}
private void SetMainWindowStartSize(int width, int height)
{
    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
        nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
        {
            var size = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(width, height);
            handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MinimumSize = size;
            handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MaximumSize = size;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MinimumSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(100, 100);
                    handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MaximumSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(5000, 5000);
                });
            });

        });
}
```