# Why the window size does not match the screen resolution and how to get the window size relative to the screen resolution mac Catalyst

Tags: c#, uikit, maui, .net-maui

My screen resolution is 1080 in height, but when I create a window (UIWindow) and set the height to 1080, the window is not created to full height. How do I make a window full screen height or get the window height so that my window opens to full screen height

My screen resolution is 1980 (width) x 1080 (height)
But I set value on next code 1080 and window open not on full screen:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
            nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
            {
                var size = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(1980, 1080);
                handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MinimumSize = size;
                handler.PlatformView.WindowScene.SizeRestrictions.MaximumSize = size;
            });
```

Comment: Please edit your tags to reflect the tech you're actually using, not every possible thing under the sun.  And it helps greatly to actually post the code instead of just describing it.  Please read [ask] for more guidance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside that method, does the breakpoint get hit? If so, then does iOS have some "Resize" method to actually apply those values?  For example, see [this code for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400003/199364) - you may need the equivalent of that "Resize" line.